# Adding a single date to the first column of a file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that looks like

```
1234-00AA12 .02
5678-11BB34 .03
```

In a bash script I have an expression like

day=$(...)

that greps a date in the format YYYY/MM/DD (if this matters), let's say 2014/01/21 for specificity.

I want to produce the following:

```
2014/01/21,1,1,1234,00AA12,.02
2014/01/21,1,1,5678,11BB34,.03
```

(The first column is the day, the second and third columns are fixed as "1").

After a bit of googling I tried:

```
cat file|awk -F "-" '{split($2,array," "); printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",$day,"1","1",$1,array[1],array[2]}'> output.csv
```

but $day isn't working with awk.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: awk is not shell. `day` is a shell variable. See Q24 in the comp.unix.shell FAQ.

Comment: @EdMorton `awk is not shell`.  Reminds one of: `GNU is not Unix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` wouldn't understand shell variables.  You need to pass those to it:

```
awk -vdd="$day" -F "-" '{split($2,array," "); printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",dd,"1","1",$1,array[1],array[2]}'
```

---

Moreover, rather than saying:

```
cat file | awk ...
```

avoid the useless use of cat:

```
awk file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this awk:

```
awk -v d=$(date '+%Y/%m/%d') '{print d,1,1,$1,$2}' OFS=, file
2014/02/07,1,1,1234-00AA12,.02
2014/02/07,1,1,5678-11BB34,.03
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v day="$day" 'BEGIN{FS="[ -]";OFS=","} {print day,1,1,$1,$2,$3}' file
2014/01/21,1,1,1234,00AA12,.02
2014/01/21,1,1,5678,11BB34,.03
```

Answer (score 0):

With bash

```
day="2014/01/21"
(
    IFS=,
    while IFS=" -" read -ra fields; do 
        new=( "$day" 1 1 "${fields[@]}" )
        echo "${new[*]}"
    done < file
)
```

```
2014/01/21,1,1,1234,00AA12,.02
2014/01/21,1,1,5678,11BB34,.03
```

I run the while loop in a subshell just to keep changes to IFS localized.